# Jar file won't start after clean Build

Tags: java, jar

I have been busy with this netbeans application for the past 5 weeks so friday I was done with it anf I wanted to deploy it I made the clean build and installed jre-8u131-windows-x64 but when I douboe click on it nothing happens. I only get that 'loading' blue circle for about a second then nothing.

I have research and researched but nothing seems to work. I even tried running it on cmd, I do not get any error even when using CMD. Please help, I must deploy it in the organization computers tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a few problems.

1. You might not have added any GUI.
2. Assuming you did, are you certain that you used the right class when creating your jar file?

   3. Did you try setting it to wumbo?

Comment: I made the app on a JFrame Form, I think that means I added the GUI.

Kindly tell me whatbis "wumbo"

Comment: @JuniorM. Oh great, swing. Unfortunately, I use FX instead so I won't really be able to help. I recommend either waiting for someone else to help you here, or asking around on Reddit, which is also a big help.